# exceeded the max connection per hour in mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exceeded the set max connections for mysql. I set it in phpmyAdmin. My problem is that I cannot get in to phpmyadmin anymore.

It was set to some number of connections per hour. Do I have towait for an hour before I can use it again or is there a way to access phpmyAdmin or restart the settings?

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me a lot, I solved this issue like this:

- Create new database user
- and set it to database
- edit your config file with the new settings

and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I presume this is a per-login setting in mysqld, in which case unless you can use a different login, or can restart mysqld you'll simply have to wait until the hour is up.

You can read more about this on the MySQL [Setting Account Resource Limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-resources.html) manual page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new user for that database. Grant that user all privileges. Then delete that user. This will reset the query limit on that database.